# Literature and the work of David Lynch

Tags: inspiration, twin-peaks, david-lynch

About a year ago I discovered *Twin Peaks* on Netflix, and I am currently enjoying every moment of season 3. I've really come to appreciate the subtleties and nuances of David Lynch's style of storytelling. While I want to dive further into his cinematic canon (which would be a question for a different SE community), I am curious about influences on his work from a literary perspective.

**Has David Lynch ever identified specific literary influences -- works and/or writers -- that have shaped the way he tells stories?** It doesn't necessarily have to be an influence on *Twin Peaks* in particular, but that would be a bonus.

Comment: Those interested in answering this question might find Lynch's book *Catching the Big Fish* helpful.